# Create devise user and profile model with same form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking to create a form with input fields for two models - Devise User model and Profile model. I want the profile model to be created with the fields and reference the User model when created.

Registration New view

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <!-- Devise Fields for User model -->
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>

   <!-- Profile model -->
    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |g| %>
       <%= g.text_field :first_name %>
       <%= g.text_field :last_name %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
<% end %>
```

User Model

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

Profile Model

```
belongs_to :user
```

Application Controller

```
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [ profile_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name]])
  end
```

Devise Registration controller (override)

```
  def new
    super do |resource|
      resource.build_profile
    end
  end
```

After filling out the form I receive an error message. Refer to the following image 
[image: Sign Up error message]

Here is the code on Github https://github.com/Goeken/Speech-today

How should I go about this?

Comment: What's in your controller?

Comment: Check the log for any unpermitted parameters. If so the issue is with configure_permitted_parameters method. Also   f.fields_for @user.build_profile can be replaced with f.fields_for :profile

Comment: Try changing `<%= f.fields_for @user.build_profile do |g| %>` to `<%= f.fields_for :profile, @user.build_profile do |g| %>`

Comment: Outputs same error.

Comment: What about this `<%= f.fields_for :profile, resource.build_profile do |g| %>`?

Comment: what are the fields for profile model? do you have first_name on that model?

Comment: @pavan Still same output

Comment: @Nezir I have many fields and I double checked just now two of them are t.string "first_name", t.string "last_name"

Comment: Do you have your custom registrations_controller? If so you need to add `@user.build_profile` in the `new` action and change it to `<%= f.fields_for :profile do |g| %>`

Comment: I don't have a custom registration controller. I'd rather not create one, but if I have to I will.  Is that the only way?

Comment: I think this `<%= f.fields_for :profile do |g| %>` should be fine. Try it.

Comment: I definitely need the profile_build in there. If I only have :profile it won't show the nested form. I'll take your advice and try creating a custom registration controller and adding @user.build_profile in there and then having only the :profile in the form. I'll update my question if it works or not.

Comment: I created the registration controller and still same results. I'll add the code to github and share the link. Maybe then someone can find the mistake I'm making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had look into your github repository code & I found that your User model code is not correct. Here's the modified user model -

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

  # You should not add first_name last_name validation message here, 
  # because those are profile model attributes, Not user model
  #validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

And rest of code are OK.
I hope it will work.

Comment: I didn't realize I had the validation in my model. It would of been helpful to everyone else helping me if they knew that was there. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to know that. Also i was contributing your github repository and make pull request. Have a look into that.